# mysql_error doesn't generate error message

Tags: php, mysql

Error message doesn't display on mysql connect failure

```
        if( ! $this->remote_connection_id = @mysql_connect($vars['hostname'], $vars['username'], $vars['password'], TRUE))
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
```

only displays `Could not connect:`

Comment: Worked for me. I got a (suppressed) warning from the failed login and mysql_error also contained the same error message about not beeing able to login without a password. PHP 5.3.8 MySQL 5.5.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ( $vars ['hostname'], $vars ['username'], $vars ['password'], "test" );
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf ( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error );
}
else
{
    echo "Am OK" ;

}
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: no no no. I meant mysql_error() doesn't display error message. I made this rootq to test error generating part. But mysql_error() doesn't display error message, you see?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parentheses properly.

Instead of:

```
if( ! $a = foo())
```

Use:

```
if( !($a = foo()))
```

The reason you get no error is because the connection was successful.

Comment: no i get php error message like `Access denied for user 'rootq'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: since it says "using password: NO", you should check that your `$vars` is set correctly.

Comment: no no no. I meant mysql_error() doesn't display error message. I made this rootq to test error generating part. But mysql_error() doesn't display error message, you see?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 connections? 
like this:

```
$link_lang_db = mysql_connect($conf_lang_db_host, $conf_lang_db_user, $conf_lang_db_password, 1) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($link_lang_db));
$link_editor_db = mysql_connect($conf_editor_db_host, $conf_editor_db_user, $conf_editor_db_password, 1) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($link_editor_db));
```

then try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query24f, $link_lang_db) or die("Error: " .mysql_error($link_lang_db));
```

Hope it helped.